# iOS - CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout Cell odd index Not Displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

- cell width -> Full size setting
- I Want Displayed all Cell
- but
- even index cell -> displayed
- odd index cell -> not displayed
- please help.. critical situation
- How to Displayed all Cell ??

Comment: can you share your tried code?

Comment: @RaviDhorajiya - Several sections exist.
Among them, I want to apply the final section of the CHTCollectionIayout.

Comment: @RaviDhorajiya - comment Thank you :) , This has been fixed using the chtcollection Method "longestColumnIndexInSection".